# Voltages for connecting ds18b20 to Edison breakout board

Tags: voltage, sensor, uart, intel

It appears that the [upm library](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/upm/blob/master/examples/python/ds18b20.py) provides support for reading temperatures from a ds18b20 on an Edison via uart. They also provide this [hookup diagram](http://iotdk.intel.com/docs/master/upm/knownlimitations.html). However, it looks like the [ds18b20 can only operate at 5V](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwji5cSs47LQAhXLgVQKHdlxBjgQFgiWATAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdatasheets.maximintegrated.com%2Fen%2Fds%2FDS18B20.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFd2GCLeMjG9dlnZUebjZMJlLphyg&bvm=bv.139250283,d.amc) while the [UART TX and RX on the breakout board are at 1.8V](http://download.intel.com/support/edison/sb/edisonbreakout_hg_331190006.pdf) (table 28). This upm diagram seems to suggest they should be directly connected though. I am hesitant to try it for fear of damaging the board or module.

Do I need to step the voltage up and down between the Edison uart and a 1-Wire bus?

If so, what would be the appropriate way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working using a [TSX010x bidirectional level shifter](http://www.ti.com/product/TXS0104E). I connected it like this:
[image: Intel Edison 1-wire hookup diagram]

I think you could also use a unidirectional level shifter between the TX and RX lines listed in the diagram and the ones on the breakout board.

Answer (score 0):

The DS18B20 can operate at 3V as well ( it is the minimum supply voltage, while 5.5V is the max supply voltage ). Table 28  also lists 3.3V as a I/O voltage. So power the DS18B20 from 3.3V and you will not need any voltage translation between the Edison and 1-Wire bus. And yes, you can use provided hookup diagram

Comment: Where are you seeing that the edison can output 3.3V? The hardware guide table 28 pretty clearly states VDD max is 1.89V.